# Subdomínios acessarem um determinado diretório sem alterar a url

Tags: php, htaccess

Tenho os seguintes subdomínios:

```
empresa1.site.com.br
empresa2.site.com.br
empresa3.site.com.br
....
```

Esses subdomínios acessarão o sistema que está dentro do seguinte diretório:

```
site.com.br/sistema/
```

Os subdomínios foram criados dentro do httpdocs/. Gostaria de fazer com que os subdomínios acessassem o sistema sem alterar a url, pois o objetivo é quando fizer quaisquer alterações e/ou inclusões de novos recursos, não tenhamos a necessidade de fazer isso dentro de todos os subdomínios, haja vista que serão dezenas ou até mesmo centenas de subdomínios. As minhas tentativas foram diretamente no .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^empresa1.site.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.empresa1.site.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.site.com/sistema/$1?key=empresa1 [P,L]
```

Onde resgato pelo PHP:

```
$diretorio = $_REQUEST["key"];
if($directory != null){
   require "http://".$diretorio.".site.com.br/sistema/class/conectCass.php";

}else{
 require "conectClass.php"; 
}
```

Mas não deu certo. Tentei diretamente pelo PHP, mas quando clico no link criado, ele me obriga que a página do link esteja dentro dos subdiretórios. Vejam:

Em cada subdomínio coloquei da seguinte forma:

```
include 'sistema/';
```

E no index.php do sistema:

```
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$host = str_replace(['www.', '.site.com.br', 'site.com.br'], '', $host);
if($host == '') {
    // entra o conteúdo do sistema
} else {
    // Entra o conteúdo do subdomínio
}
```

Em ambos não funcionaram. Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Questões de configuração de serviços, aplicações e infraestrutura devem ser feitas em inglês no [su] ou [sf] conforme o assunto, separadamente da parte de programação. Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas de cada comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Comment: Resolvido o problema de configuração do servidor, se restar alguma dúvida da parte PHP pode [edit] a postagem e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema, que a pergunta é reavaliada pela própria comunidade. Sobre os comentários removidos, importante uma lida no [código de conduta](/conduct). Para evitar que a situação saia da normalidade, os comentários foram bloqueados nesta postagem. Consulte todos os links passados para maiores detalhes.